# How to parse a schema with XMLTYPE in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd, xmltype

I am trying to create a process that will check in production that the changes that we made in a XML Schema were deployed. the files are being kept in an Oracle DB and there fore I was thinking of using XMLTYPE.extract ....

the problem is that xpath is having trouble parsing a schema.

### if this is my Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="TRB_TRX">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="HEADER">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="ReqNotf" type="xs:string" use="optional" default="N"/>
```

### I want to be able to do

```
SELECT XMLTYPE(COLUMN).EXTRACT('//xs:attribute[@name="ReqNotf"]/@type').getStringVal() 
From .....
```

Comment: What problems are you encountering? You must anyway declare the used namespace.

Comment: I am running the following query (for example): 
    select extractValue(xmltype(FILE_DATA), '//xs:element/@name/text()') from MY_TABLE 

 and getting the error:" ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '//xs:element/@name/text()'. and getting "

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
 EXTRACT(col,'//xs:attribute[@name="ReqNotf"]/@type', 
  'xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"').getStringVal() as val
```

Example

```
SELECT EXTRACT(col,'//xs:attribute[@name="ReqNotf"]/@type', 'xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"').getStringVal() as val
From (
select 
XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="TRB_TRX">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="HEADER">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="ReqNotf" type="xs:string" use="optional" default="N"/>
                </xs:complexType> 
           </xs:element>  
        </xs:sequence>           
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>') as COL from dual
);

 VAL 
-------------
xs:string
```

Do not use `COLUMN` as column name its reserved.

Also consider using XMLTABLE - EXTRACT is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions060.htm#SQLRF00640http://).